# why i can't put view binding inside onClick listener?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

i already define this :

```
class ProfileFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {}
```

and the onclick :

```
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when (v!!.id) {
            binding.tvNavSetting -> {
                avoidDoubleClicks(binding.tvNavSetting)
                val intent = Intent(requireContext(), SettingsActivity::class.java)
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my Drawer & inside Profile Fragment.xml :

```
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
                    app:elevation="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                    android:paddingBottom="100dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">
    
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
    
                        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:id="@+id/seach_view"
                            android:background="@drawable/bg_search"
                            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"/>
    
// this is what i try to call://// 
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_nav_setting"
                            android:text="awdadw"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    
                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/drawer_bg" />
    
                    </LinearLayout>
    
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_keluar_profile"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Keluar"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_login"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
    
                </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

i have Text View inside the Drawer Navigation inside Fragment.. i want handle click in that drawer navigation, but the text view can't call by viewBinding..  please have a look the error picture below..

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry , i forgot to add this :

```
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    when (v!!.id) {
        R.id.tv_nav_setting -> {   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            avoidDoubleClicks(binding.tvNavSetting)
            val intent = Intent(requireContext(), SettingsActivity::class.java)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}

/*adding this line solve the problem*/
private fun setDrawer() {
    binding.drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
    binding.tvNavSetting.setOnClickListener(this)  <<<-------
}
```

Comment: well, that works, but this isn't proper approach. binding pattern was introduced for not-handling "manually" ids of `View`s. if you have automatically binded view, then you should obtain its id, not referencking manually, as you may make some mistake here and click won't occur. for such situations binding was introduced - avoiding such "bugs"

Comment: Read my answer for the proper method for implementing a bulk on click listener.

Answer (score 0):

`when(v!!.id)` means you want to use view with particular id (works like old Java `switch case` or just `if(view.id == id)`, so `binding.tvNavSetting -> ...` should be `binding.tvNavSetting.id -> ...`. currently you are comparing views id with whole view-object itself

Comment: sorry, but -->> binding.tvNavSetting.id didn't works , and recently i just found the answer.. _-_

Comment: could you please post what kind of problem your IDE have with `binding.tvNavSetting.id` ? what is the message?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using view ids in when(`v!!.id`), we can use the comparison of views.

i.e Bind Listenser first

```
    binding.bt1.setOnClickListener(this)
    binding.bt2.setOnClickListener(this)
    binding.bt3.setOnClickListener(this)
    binding.bt4.setOnClickListener(this)
```

then

```
override fun onClick(view: View?) {
    binding.apply {
        when(view) {
            bt1 -> {
                println("bt1")
            }
            bt2 -> {
                println("bt2")
            }
            bt3 -> {
                println("bt3")
            }
            bt4 -> {
                println("bt4")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Works perfectly since `binding.bt1` gives `View` only.